# python で　with open関数の引数に変数を設定できますか？

Tags: python

pythonを使って
with open('n.text','w')
とした時に　n＝１００　と代入してファイルを書き出したいのですが良い方法はありますか？

Answer (score 1):

`n = 100`として`100.text`というファイルを書き出したいということでしょうか?

`+`という演算子を使って文字列を結合させることができます。また、`str`を使って数値を文字列に変換できます。これらを使って以下のようにできます。

```
n = 100
with open(str(n) + ".text", "w")
```

Comment: `"{}.txt".format(n)`とかもいいですね．